# Form for 3 association models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am still a newbie so please forgive this silly question. I got 3 models:
- User (generated by devise), Comment and Post

- User has many posts and comments
- Comment belongs to both post and user
- Post has many comments and belongs to user

My routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
   end  
end
```

My form code:

```
<%= form_for([@user,@post,@comment]) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

I want to generate to `user_post_comments_path` but the above `form_for` generate to `post_comments_path`. Why? Did I misunderstand something. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rails routing and Form handling is very confusing and I still get it wrong all the time...

I think that your problem is that some of your variables is not set (`nil`) and so rails can not determine what you are actually up to.

I would also like to recommend to you that you don't nest your routes like that unless you have to for the sake of the urls.

It's usually enough to nest one level deep and use the `current_user` to assign to models when creating them. This also reduces the security risk involved when posting ids of other users:

```
def create
   @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
   [...]
end

def create
   @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
   @comment.post = Post.find params[:post_id]
   [...]
end
```

Comment: To create a post of current user, I did the same way as you recommended before. But the thing here is I want to create the COMMENT of a USER inside a POST. So here we have 3 model relation. Right now I use this trick 
    $comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    $comment.user_id = params[:user_id]
    $comment.post_id = params[:post_id]
which doesn't have any thing to do with relation. It just set the attributes manually. Any recommends ?